# C# Windows Form Application Processing Payments?

Tags: c#, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I have a windows form application made and I am curious how to setup payment processing? I've asked some people and they say you can use a PayPal link and they can pay through there. I'm concerned about how the program would know if the person paid? Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to use PayPal you'll need to consult their [API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to check [Paypal Ipn](https://www.paypal.com/ipn) and you can check payment is successful or not.

(Actually this is a comment for question)